# May gentiles acquire other gentiles as slaves

Tags: halacha, gentiles, choshen-mishpat-civil-law, noachide-laws, slave-serve-eved-avadim

According to Halacha, is a gentile allowed to acquire another gentile as a slave? Jews are allowed to have  other Jews be slaves, so does the Same principle apply here? Say that the law allows for it so we’ll forget Dina D’malchuta Dina for example

Comment: Gentiles own slaves all the time in tanach. Take Gen 20:8 וַיַּשְׁכֵּם אֲבִימֶלֶךְ בַּבֹּקֶר וַיִּקְרָא לְכָל-עֲבָדָיו

Comment: @DoubleAA that's not necessarily referring to slaves- it could be servants

Comment: Btw, Jews are _not_ allowed to own other Jews. Definitely not in the way Jews can own gentiles

Comment: @Loani You mean at-will employees? Is there any reason to think that was the intention?

Comment: @DoubleAA like any king had his entourage of servants: men-at-arms, butlers, stable boys, etc. They weren't all slaves

Comment: Noah condemning his son Ham to slavery (Gen. 9:25) would be an interesting twist if slavery is impermissible among the children of Noah...

Comment: @kirk I think the question is almost off point and should be focused on what's allowable in Eretz Yisrael. It's mute in the Noahide laws and any society governed by the Noahide laws would have very little reason to allow such behavior. Especially since in civilized nations of modern times the trend has been to elevate the worth of a human being and outlaw slavery. Even if found permissible by Torah, it would not be rational to step backward to a lesser ideal for the human race to when the practice was more common.

Comment: As is clear in Vayikra, they may even buy Jewish slaves (and it is stated that one must be honest in redeeming them, indicating it's a legitimate enterprise)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Shulchan Aruch (Yoreh De'ah 267:10) it says:

> במה דברים אמורים שכשלקח עבד מהעובד כוכבים אין הגוף קנוי לו? כשאותו עובד כוכבים קנה אותו עבד על ידי שנמכר לו הוא עצמו. אבל אם קנאו בדינא דמלכותא דקני ליה גופיה. ולקחו ממנו ישראל, אם קדם וטבל לשם בן חורין -- לא קנה עצמו בו חורין.
>
> What is the case in which we say that one who buys a slave from a gentile, the slaves body doesn't belong to him [until he immerses for the purpose of slavery, see the previous seif]? When that gentile [whom he bought the slave from] bought the slave through the slave selling himself. But if he was bought through the kingdom's laws, in which the slave's body belongs to  his [gentile] master, and a Jew bought the slave from him, if the slave immersed with the purpose of becoming a free Jew, it doesn't work [because his body is already owned].

So we see that a gentile can both be sold according to local law to another gentile, and can sell himself into slavery to another gentile. However, if a gentile seems himself into slavery, his body is still considered his own (maybe it'd be considered sort of like an עבד עברי status), whereas if he's sold by law, it'd follow whatever the law states (and presumably his body would belong to his master).